# C map/hash-table that's keyed by integers and maps to void pointers

Tags: c, data-structures, dictionary, hashtable, hashmap

I am re-writing a light weight image server I wrote in Python using epoll into c (not c++). I want to write a (or use an existing) very simple map or hash-table that maps integer keys (file descriptors) to void pointers. What's a good way to go about doing this? I don't need to be able to support any generic types of keys or even strings. I have one idea:

```
// Initialize map.
size_t map_size = 50;
void ** map = (void **)malloc(sizeof(void *) * map_size);
memset((void *)map, 0, map_size);

// Set values for keys 3, 20, 67
int key_a = 3;
int key_b = 20;
int key_c = 67;
void * value_a = ...;
void * value_b = ...;
void * value_c = ...;

// NOTE: This does not take into account conflicting keys. I would probably solve
// that using an array or linked-list and comparing keys.
map[key_a % map_size] = value_a;
map[key_b % map_size] = value_b;
map[key_c % map_size] = value_c;
```

Is this sensible or are there much better ways to accomplish this? Or can someone point me in the right direction to finding an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a simple modulus as a "hash algorithm" per se, but it only works well if you know the results will be evenly distributed. In your case, however, you can't technically count on that with file descriptors, since there's no particular guarantee as to what numbers you'll get back from the open/fopen calls.

There are very simple hash algorithms out there that are pretty fast and work well enough for general use cases. You could consider the [FNV family](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/), or even the dead-simple Pearson hash.

That said, I'm a bit curious as to why you want a hash table keyed off of file descriptors. That seems like an odd design detail, and makes me think you're overcomplicating something.

Comment: There is a guarantee about what numbers you'll get back from an `open()` call - it returns [the lowest file descriptor not already open for the process](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html).

Comment: My reason is that I want to be able to map these file descriptors to structs that contain information (request URI, whether the response is ready, response data, response size, bytes of response sent) specific to each file descriptor. The file descriptors come from listening to a socket bound to an IP address and port and registered with epoll.

Answer (score 3):

File descriptors are small integers on most systems, and often contiguous, as they are used as indices inside the kernel. Hence I propose to just create an array from 0..maxfd (growing dynamically), and use the file descriptor as an integer - with no hashing at all.

As a safe guard, you may want to protect against systems that use different strategies for allocating file descriptors, e.g. aborting if it is larger than 2^20.

Comment: The c-type of file descriptor is an `int` which on most modern systems is a 32bit integer (even on 64bit systems and not to be confused with `long`). I read somewhere that the max size of a file descriptor is 65535 (an unsigned 16bit integer) but I don't know if that's constant. So I can only relay on the size of the data type and that is far larger of an array than I would like to allocate. Especially since I don't think the size of the array needs to be orders of magnitude larger than the maximum number of simultaneous connections (file descriptors) that it will use.

Comment: That the type of a file descriptor is int doesn't mean that implementations necessarily exhaust the entire value space of int. On the systems you care about (i.e. those implementing epoll - Linux), you can rely on much more.

Answer (score 3):

Use the public-domain implementation of a generic C hash table in Ruby's codebase -- [st.c](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/st.c?view=markup).

Comment: No repositories found

Answer (score 1):

Others have raised good points about whether this is really what you want to do, but just to answer your immediate question, the [glibc hashtable functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/hsearch) should be available on most systems.  Note that you almost certainly want to use the `_r` variants (`hcreate_r, hsearch_r, hdestroy_r`), since the vanilla versions create and manipulate a single, global hashtable.

Comment: I already looked into that glibc hash-table functions but then you're limited to only one hash-table at a time, which I don't want to be restricted by.

Comment: I don't think that's right.  As I mentioned in my response above, use the *_r function variants which take a handle to the table and allow you to create multiple tables at once.

Comment: The glibc hashtables are keyed by string, not integer.